# acción save no me guarda en la base de datos Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buen día, tengo un problema al hacer una actualización en mi base de datos con **active record**, en particular realizo lo siguiente y en teoría me da un resultado satisfactorio pero, no guarda nada en la tabla beneficiario

```
          @beneficiario = Beneficiario.find(@envio.beneficiario_id)
              begin
                @beneficiario.telefono = params[:beneficiario][:telefono]
                @beneficiario.calle = params[:beneficiario][:calle]
                @beneficiario.exterior = params[:beneficiario][:exterior]
                @beneficiario.interior = params[:beneficiario][:interior]
                @beneficiario.colonia = params[:beneficiario][:colonia]
                @beneficiario.codigo_postal = params[:beneficiario][:codigo_postal]
                @beneficiario.localidad = params[:beneficiario][:localidad]
                @beneficiario.municipio = params[:beneficiario][:municipio]
                @beneficiario.created_on = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
                @beneficiario.updated_on = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")                    
                @beneficiario.save!
               rescue Exception => e
                  puts "Expecion #{e}"
```

En el resultado por terminal obtengo lo siguiente

```
UPDATE `beneficiarios` SET `beneficiario_real` = 0, `pais_residencia` = 'MEX', `destino_recursos` = 'Manutencion', `monto_pesos` = 26452.0, `ppe_funciones` = '', `localidad` = 'MORELIA, MICH', `cantidad_mensual` = '200', `ppe_periodo` = '', `clave_actividad_economica` = '0100008', `exterior` = '12', `sexo` = '1', `nacionalidad` = 'MEXICANA', `ocupacion` = 'agricultor', `estado` = 'MR', `clave_localidad` = '01953009', `interior` = '13', `tipo_de_forma_migratoria` = 'PFM', `pais_nacionalidad` = 'MEX', `numero_forma_migratoria` = '', `codigo_postal` = '79928', `origen_recursos` = 'trabajo', `ppe_puesto` = '', `colonia` = 'mistery', `lugar_nacim` = 'MICHOACAN', `pais` = 'MEX', `parentesco_ppe` = 0, `created_on` = '2020-07-29 19:36:25', `envios_mensuales` = '1', `monto` = 26452.0, `ppe_dependencia` = '', `ppe` = 0, `telefono` = '4432589646', `calle` = 'enigma street', `numero_envios` = 1 WHERE `id` = 18918
```

Posteriormente me imprime un
**ROLLBACK**
el hash **params** ya valide que si venga con datos de la vista sin ningún problema.

Si alguien me pudiera orientar en que está sucediendo o como enterarme de cuál es el error se los agradeceria.

Comment: Revisa `@beneficiario.errors.messages` después de llamar a `.save` para ver cual es el error de validación, en caso de que haya uno. Sino, agrega a tu pregunta cual es la excepción que te está arrojando y estás rescatando

Comment: Creo que si el problema fuera de validación, no aparecería el `UPDATE` en la terminal. ¿Podría ser que la tabla tiene alguna restricción, como un campo único o similar?

Comment: @beneficiario.errors.messages me lanza un error de undefined method `messages' for #<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x7f740d0b09b8> y no me aparece ningun error o excetion ni nada, aparentemente hace todo pero me manda el rollbak

Comment: @FelipeG: si `messages` no está definido, me suena a que tienes una versión de Rails antigua, probablemente Rails 3 or anterior. ¿Qué tal si usas `@beneficiario.errors.full_messages` en su lugar?

Comment: Si estoy usando rails 2.3.4, no fue mi decisión, y tampoco me funciona tampoco @beneficiario.errors.full_messages

Answer (score 0):

Un par de cosas, veo que tienes created_on y updated_on, estos se han generado en la base de datos? normalmente se llaman created_at y updated_at (me imagino que es por la versión de rails) si le quitas el set que haces en estos campos deben autogenerarse, podría estar dando error de que no puedes aplicar el cambio al created_on y updated_on (ya que se autogeneran estos valores).

También tu rescue te manda a Exception => e si solo lo dejas como:

```
rescue => e
```

ya que solo pasaria a rescue si el error es de clase Exception.
Y finalmente, que te pone la consola? además del ROLLBACK si pudieras sacar un screenshot sería muy útil.